# Opinions on Siacoin's cloud hosting platform? You mine Siacoins by hosting files, and their current storage rates are 10x less than AWS

Tags: altcoin, network, hosting, amazon-web-services

I was hoping to get some insight on how useful or competitive Siacoin's file hosting platform is compared to competitors. You mine Siacoins by hosting parts of files, and they claim for their cloud storage rates to be significantly lower than that of AWS, Google Cloud, and Microsoft Azure.

[image: siacouns price savings]

You need to have 2,000 Siacoins in order to begin hosting files and earning Siacoins. I know much of the cryptocurrency pricing today is effected by speculation, but I was wondering if anyone knows how it compares to the speed, availability, and usefulness of platforms like Amazon Web Services.

[image]

I am asking because I really like Siacoin's approach to use cryptocurrency for tangible cloud hosting, as it is reminiscent of Torrents, but am hoping to get other opinions on the current state and potential of their platform. Do you think their platform is ready to used on a professional level, or if it has potential? And if anyone has a programmers perspective on the usefulness of their platform, I would love to know!